# Trying to get data from SQL in my WPF application

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, xaml

I am trying to get data from my SQL Server, but its not working.

in my application I have two projects one called Db and one called App.
in the db I am using the dbml for accessing the Database and I can find the code for insert, update and delete, but nothing to get it.

**in my code behind for the xaml I have this call.**

```
DbEstimatorDataContext conn = new DbEstimatorDataContext();

        List<Company_Control> Company_Controls = (from s in  conn.Company_Controls () 
                                                  select s).ToList();
```

**I am getting the following error**
*Non-invocable member 'dbBusiness.DbEstimatorDataContext.Company_Controls' cannot be used like a method.*

**My binding in the XAML looks like this but I have not even been able to try and reference this yet.**

```
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Parent_Company}" Header="Parent Company"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Company_Id}"  Header="Company Id"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Company_Name}"  Header="Company Name"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Company_address_1}"  Header="Company Address 1"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Company_address_2}"  Header="Company Address 2"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Company_city}"  Header="Company City"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding State}"  Header="State"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Postal_Code}"  Header="Postal Code"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Accounting_Code}"  Header="Accounting Code"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Active}"  Header="Active"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Control_Key}"  Header="Control Key"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Credit_Check}"  Header="Credit Check"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Customer_Account_Source}"  Header="Customer Account Source"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Customer_Account_Format}"  Header="Customer Account Format"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Overrun_Percent}"  Header="Overrun Percent"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  DataMemberBinding="{Binding Switches}"  Header="Switches"/>
                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

**Where is the get, should be something that says "select * from Company_Control"?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates you should delete the () after conn.Company_Controls - it is a property, not a method.

Comment: Thanks, I was beginning to think I had to create a stored procedure to get the data